# After logging in my password does not work

Tags: 14.04, password

I'm running a fresh install of ubuntu 14.04 and I've got a strange problem. When I login to the GUI I successfully get to my desktop and can use everything fine, but as soon as I try to sudo anything, it does not accecpt my password. I also cannot use the GUI to change my password as when I enter my existing password, it says it is incorrect. Also, if I lock my machine and try to log back in it claims my password is incorrect, but if I hit the switch user option and choose the same account, I can then enter my password and I get back in.

Any ideas what is causing this?

Cheers

Comment: Can you verify that you use the same keyboard layout for the login screen and your desktop session?

Answer (score 1):

Ignore me, found the problem ... Im running this on a MACBook Pro and for some reason the installation has created 2 keyboard configs and my password has a £ sign in it. At the GUI login prompt initially it must use the keyboard layout when Shift+3 is a £ sign, but after logging in it switches to a different keyboard layout where Shift+3 maps to the # symbol, and obviously then my password does not work.

I'll sort my keyboard layouts and I'll be fine. :)